# Analysis of a function: Showing that Quantum Mechanics violates relativity

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

Consider the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and a self-adjoint, positive operator $H$ (Hamiltonian).

Let $\psi_t$ be a solution to the Schrödinger equation (with $\psi_0$ the initial condition), then consider the function

$$t \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{f(\boldsymbol{x})} e^{-iHt} \psi_0(\boldsymbol{x}) \ d^dx.$$

Assume that $\psi_o$ is compactly supported in some ball of radius $r>0$ centred at the origin.

I am supposed to be observing how quantum mechanics violates special relativity by showing that the support of $\psi_t$ grows faster than the speed of light, but I'm lost as to where to go with this.

How to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Surely this is only true if you use a nonrelativistic Hamiltonian?

Comment: What part exactly? We are using a non-relativistic Hamiltonian above, and I am attempting to use this to show that non-relativistic quantum mechanics does indeed violate relativity (even though the name obviously implies it does!)

Comment: You never specified what Hamiltonian you were using... if $H$ is a relativistic Hamiltonian, then I expect causality to be preserved.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry. I should have been more explicit. We are using a non-relativistic Hamiltonian above and showing that causality is indeed not preserved.

Comment: Sections 2.1 of the QFT textbook by Peskin and Schroder discusses this question (and then 2.4 shows how graduating from quantum mech to quantum field theory resolves it). However it is at a physicist's level of rigor, which I doubt will be suitable for your needs. Let me see if I can massage it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Peskin and Schroeder, the argument goes 
$$
U(t) = \langle x\mid e^{-i(p^2/2m)t}\mid x_0\rangle\\
 = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\langle x\mid e^{-i(p^2/2m)t}\mid p\rangle\langle p\mid x_0\rangle\\
 = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int dp^3 e^{-i(p^2/2m)t}e^{ip(x-x_0)}\\
=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i t}\right)^{3/2}e^{im(x-x_0)^2/2t}.
$$

That the propagator does not vanish for space-like separated $x$, $x_0$ implies violation of causality.

So instead of a generic positive Hamiltonian, he's assuming a free nonrelativistic Hamiltonian $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$. And instead of assuming an initial state that has compact support, I think he's assuming here a Dirac delta function. For a generic function of compact support, I think just insert its Fourier transform, and proceed as above.

Then they talk about the Hamiltonian $H=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$, and how the problems with this Hamiltonian are the same, via an asymptotic argument through Bessel functions only vaguely alluded to, you wind up with $U(t)\sim e^{-m\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}.$ Note that this shows, contrary to what I said in the comments, using a relativistic Hamiltonian does not enforce causality (but switching from a quantum mechanics to a quantum field theory does).

The general case, with an arbitrary self-adjoint positive Hamiltonian, may proceed similarly, but the details were too vague for me to follow.